# Using Having Sum with Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL command that I am trying to convert to a LINQ to SQL command, but am having difficulties.

My SQL command follows:

```
SELECT purchs.iclientid, ifeatureid, AddnlOptionList FROM purchs
WHERE AddnlOptionList <> ''
GROUP BY purchs.iclientid, ifeatureid, AddnlOptionList
HAVING (SUM(noptions) > 0)
```

I've managed to get this far following examples:

```
var q =
   from purchs in db.Purchases
   group q by purchs.noptions into g
   where purchs.AddnlOptionList != ""
      && g.Sum(x => x.noptions) > 0
   select q;
```

However, I seem to be stuck on group q with the following two errors:

```
Cannot use local variable 'q' before it is declared

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<decimal?> because it is not a delegate type
```

An example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318380/sql-query-in-linq-with-having-sum) says that this should work, although it uses a join, and I am not. Any help would be appreciated.

**SOLUTION**

I had to modify Xiaoy312's code a little bit to get what I wanted, so I figured I would post it here in hopes that it might help someone in the future. Thank you @Xiaoy312 for the help.

```
var updates = db.Purchases
   .Where(p => p.AddnlOptionList != "")
   .GroupBy(p => new { p.iclientid, p.ifeatureid, p.AddnlOptionList })
   .Where(g => g.Sum(p => p.noptions) > 0)
   .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: Why are you using `q` in your query?  Shouldn't you do `group purchs by ...`?

Comment: @juharr - That was what I got from the sample I was following. When I change it to "group purchs by", my where clause stops working - Does not contain a definition...

Comment: That example has `group c by...` and it starts with `from c in db.City`.  Basically you have to group on something you pull from a source.  Right now you're trying to group on the local variable that you want to assign the results to.

Comment: Your part of your where clause needs to go before the grouping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put both the `WHERE` and `HAVING` clause into a single `where`. I'm less familiar with the other syntax, so here is the method syntax one :

```
var results = db.Purchases
    .Where(p => p.AddnlOptionList != "")
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.notions, p.iclientid, p.ifeatureid })
    .Where(g => g.Sum(p => p.notions) > 0)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
```

EDIT: converted to Linq syntax.

```
var results = from p in db.Purchases
              where p.AddnlOptionList != ""
              group p by new { p.notions, p.iclientid, p.ifeatureid } into g
              where g => g.Sum(p => p.notions) > 0
              from p in g
              select p;
```

EDIT: I've miss read the sql command. It meant to only pull the groups, not every item in each group.

```
// method syntax
db.Purchases
    .Where(p => p.AddnlOptionList != "")
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.notions, p.iclientid, p.ifeatureid })
    .Where(g => g.Sum(p => p.notions) > 0)
    .Select(g => g.Key)

// query syntax
    from p in db.Purchases
    where p.AddnlOptionList != ""
    group p by new { p.notions, p.iclientid, p.ifeatureid } into g
    where g.Sum(p => p.notions) > 0
    select new { g.Key.notions, g.Key.iclientid, g.Key.ifeatureid };
```

Comment: Made the conversion for you ;)

Comment: @Aron Are you sure that's going to do a `SelectMany`?

Comment: That got me results back, but I have twice what I get from the original statement. I'm trying to figure out what is causing that now.